# cordova facebook plugin login error on android

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a problem that I couldn't figure out!(I'm, kinda new at this though)
I am trying to run a cordova app on android platform(using a Mac and eclipse-luna), the build is successful, but when I'm trying to login with facebook nothing happens and I get this error in the LogCat:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: facebookConnectPlugin is not defined"

I tried everything I could think of(including lots of posts here at stackoverflow) and nothing solved it.

I would really appreciate any help!

the js code -

```
var facebookLogin=function()
{
      var fbLoginSuccess3 = function (userData) 
      {
                var str=JSON.stringify(userData);
                var id=userData["authResponse"].userID;
                 $.mobile.loading('show');
                   var promise = $.ajax({
                                        type: 'GET',
                                        url: "https://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"?        fields=first_name,last_name,email,picture.width(450).height(450)&access_token="+userData["authResponse"].accessToken,
                                        dataType: 'json'
                                      });

                                      promise.fail( function() {
                                            $.mobile.loading('hide');

                                      });

                                      promise.done( function(result) 
                                      {
                                             //alert(JSON.stringify(result));
                                             var first_name=result.first_name;
                                             var last_name=result.last_name;
                                             var email=result.email;
                                             var profileImgUrl=result.picture.data.url;

                                              String.prototype.replaceAll = function(str1, str2, ignore) 
                                              {
                                                return this.replace(new RegExp(str1.replace(/([\/\,\!\\\^\$\{\}\[\]\(\)\.\*\+\?\|\<\>\-\&])/g,"\\$&"),(ignore?"gi":"g")),(typeof(str2)=="string")?str2.replace(/\$/g,"$$$$"):str2);
                                              }
                                             profileImgUrl=profileImgUrl.replaceAll("&","^");

                                             //alert(id+" "+first_name+" "+last_name+" "+email+" "+profileImgUrl);

                                             facebookLoginHandler(id,first_name,last_name,email,profileImgUrl);
                                      });


       }
       //alert("before login");
        facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile","email"],fbLoginSuccess3,function (error) { alert("" + error) });

}
```

cordova_plugins.js -

```
cordova.define('cordova/plugin_list', function(require, exports, module) {
module.exports = [
    {
        "file": "plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/facebookConnectPlugin.js",
        "id": "com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect.FacebookConnectPlugin",
        "clobbers": [
            "facebookConnectPlugin"
        ]
    },

module.exports.metadata = 
// TOP OF METADATA
{
    "com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect": "0.11.0",
    "org.apache.cordova.camera": "0.3.4",
    "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser": "0.5.4",
    "org.apache.cordova.splashscreen": "0.3.5",
    "org.apache.cordova.file": "1.3.3",
    "org.apache.cordova.file-transfer": "0.5.0"
}
// BOTTOM OF METADATA
});
```

Comment: your code is ok.. i think there is a problem on plugin installation.can u post in cordova_plugin.js what is the facebook module object

Comment: check the facebookConnectPlugin.js path in the "file" key in cordova_plugins.js.I think the path should be 
"file": "plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/www/phonegap/plugin/facebookConnectPlugin/facebookConnectPlugin.js"

Comment: i dont have a path like you describe, i added the project hierarchy.